# File upload tool

Tags: c#, java, silverlight, html

I would like to create a image file upload tool. The tool when started up and would ask the user what directory they would like to monitor and upload files from. In the background the tool would then post securely to a web service of some sort.

Constraints solution should work on Mac and Windows computers. I would like to make the upload process pretty automatic with little user intervention.

Basically the question I have is what would you use to create application that either runs in the background or foreground to basically continuously uploads files to a web server?

I have a couple of thoughts:

- HTML5 using web workers (concerns accessing local files not sure the best way to do that)
- Silverlight (my guess is I would have to sign the application)
- Java web start application (Signing application)
- Flash (scared of this idea)

I can do the Java web start application easy enough. Both HTML5 and Silverlight are things that I would like to know. I really don't care about flash at this point.

Comment: Well if you're talking about mac you must use moonlight instead of silverlight

Comment: No moonlight is needed for Linux, Silverlight works on both Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can use the JNotify library: http://jnotify.sf.net . It works on Windows, OS X, and Linux.

I don't know about C# or HTML5. HTML5 (last I checked circa July 2011) doesn't have a filesystem API. In reality you need an app that can be distributed so it can run in the background, so Silverlight is out of the question. If I am misinterpreting your problem, please tell me.

Comment: Great link on the jnotify. Been using Java for sometime and haven't ever used it. Looks like a great lib for checking when files change.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on JNotify. I will give that a shot see how I like web start integration. I may have to roll custom application for each platform.

Comment: @Paul Kling you should be able to embed it in a JNLP file with the native libraries option (I haven't tried it, YMMV.) Also, Farmor's answer below also describes that you need to sign the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go with a signed Java applet if you can foresee the need for downloading as well. It is difficult to find a good download solution other then a signed Java applet. A signed Java applet let's you push things to the users filesystem allowing for upload as well as download.

Comment: Wish I could click yes to yours as well.